# Laravel: csv validations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, duplicates

How i can validate fields in csv file before uploading.

I want to get all duplicate email ids from csv file before uploading which are already available in db.

and if there is duplciate in file than upload the other except duplicate and after uploading display all duplicate email ids

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $upload = $request->file('upload-file');
    $getPath = $upload->getRealPath();

    $file = fopen($getPath,'r');        

    while($columns = fgetcsv($file))
    {
        if($columns[0]=="")
        continue;


        $data =  $columns;


        foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {
            $name = $data[0];
            $email = $data[1];
            $password = $data[2];

        }

        try{
            $user = User::Create(
                [
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'password'=>$password,
                ]);
            $user->save();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
          if($e->getCode() == 23000)
              return 'we have found duplicate records';
          else
              $e->getCode();
        };

    }
```

Comment: your try catch should be within the foreach so you can check each user instead of the last user. Of course if you don't also need to create the user you can just do a `array_count_values(array_column($data, 1))` to see how many emails are included more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do like this.

```
      public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $upload = $request->file('upload-file');
        $getPath = $upload->getRealPath();

        $file = fopen($getPath,'r');        

        while($columns = fgetcsv($file))
        {
            if($columns[0]=="")
            continue;


            $data =  $columns;


            foreach($data as $key=>$value)
            {
                $name = $data[0];
                $email = $data[1];
                $password = $data[2];

            }

            try{
             if (!User::whereEmail($email)->exists()) {
                $user = User::Create(
                    [
                        'name'=>$name,
                        'email'=>$email,
                        'password'=>$password,
                    ]);
                $user->save();
             }
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
              if($e->getCode() == 23000)
                  return 'we have found duplicate records';
              else
                  $e->getCode();
            };

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, Create any array variable private, public etc (what ever you want) and push all excel values to that variable and find unique results set from that array using php function and store them into database.

```
public $records = [];
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $upload = $request->file('upload-file');
    $getPath = $upload->getRealPath();

    $file = fopen($getPath,'r');        

    while($columns = fgetcsv($file))
    {
        if($columns[0]=="")
        continue;


        $data =  $columns;
        array_push($this->records, data);



    }
}

array_unique($this->records)//it will give you unique results set and insert bulk insert
```

Comment: i think my question is not cleaer.... for exapmle i have 2 emails available in db a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com..... and same are avalable in csv with 1 new id c@gmail.com..... than when i hit submit button to upload it gives me error that this this ids are already available and this is a new id...